# Issues running GPT-J-6B demo inference on colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, gpt-3

I'm trying to run the GPT-J 6B demo available here : https://colab.research.google.com/github/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax/blob/master/colab_demo.ipynb

Unfortunatelay I have some issues that are blocking me so far :

Firstly, when I'm running this part (the first cell of the colab notebook)

```
!apt install zstd

# the "slim" version contain only bf16 weights and no optimizer parameters, which minimizes bandwidth and memory
!time wget -c https://the-eye.eu/public/AI/GPT-J-6B/step_383500_slim.tar.zstd

!time tar -I zstd -xf step_383500_slim.tar.zstd

!git clone https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax.git
!pip install -r mesh-transformer-jax/requirements.txt

# jax 0.2.12 is required due to a regression with xmap in 0.2.13
!pip install mesh-transformer-jax/ jax==0.2.12 tensorflow==2.5.0
```

I don't understand why it try to download several versions of tensorflow while it's specified "tensorflow==2.5.0" in the code.
Installing all these versions take a very long time.
Here is a screenshot of a part of the output:
[output (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZPSF.png)

Moreover, at the end of the execution, I have this :
[excecution's end message (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oHnt.png)

Then, when trying to import the libraries in the following code cells, I receive missing modules errors. The missing modules seems to vary depending on the result of the first execution cell.
[missing module (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVmOl.png)

I believe that colab run out of disk memory trying to download model and dependencies but why this demo exists on colab if it can't be run on it ?